Steam: How to get manifest gid for older game versions
I’m trying to get the Manifest  GID for a specific BuildID, not just the latest version, which I'm able to find:
from steam.client import SteamClient 
from steam.guard import generate_twofactor_code_for_time
import base64, time

def get_depot_manifests(app_id, depot_id):
    try:
        client = SteamClient()
        client.login(
            username="username", 
            password="password",
            two_factor_code=generate_twofactor_code_for_time(
                base64.b64decode("shared_secret"),
                int(time.time())
            )
        )

        app_info = client.get_product_info(apps=[app_id])
        depot_info = app_info['apps'][app_id]['depots'].get(str(depot_id), {})
        
        manifests = []
        if gid := depot_info['manifests'].get('public', {}).get('gid'):
            manifests.append(('public', gid))
            
        for build_id, build in depot_info['manifests'].get('builds', {}).items():
            if gid := build.get('gid'):
                manifests.append((build_id, gid))
                
        return manifests
    except:
        return None

manifests = get_depot_manifests(730, 2347770) # Counter-Strike 2
if manifests:
    for build_id, gid in manifests:
        print(f"Build: {build_id}, GID: {gid}")

Does anyone know how to retrieve the GID for an older version of a game? Ideally, I’d like to do this using the ValvePython steam library (https://github.com/ValvePython/steam), but I’m open to any method.
Another possible way for me is the method SteamDB is using. I’ve noticed that SteamDB lists manifestids for older builds, such as https://steamdb.info/depot/2347770/manifests/. Does anyone know how SteamDB fetches these?
